# Disable drop table in liquibasev

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

when i run liquibase:diff maven command liquibase is generating a changelog with drop table changesets (the existing database contains other tables).
I want to disable this behaviour without modifying the liquibase-core how can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You may deny permissions to drop table and use liquibase preconditions to handle it.

Another solution is to change script and add  tag with new checksum.